# Contour plots and confidence intervals

Tags: confidence-interval, chi-squared-test

If I have a grid of Chi-squared values for a grid of 5 values for 1 parameter and 5 values of another parameters (5x5), can I then create a contour plot for the confidence regions?

```
X=np.linspace(0.01,0.1,5)
Y=np.linspace(0.01,0.5,5)
```

and
Z is 25 values of the chi-squared for each fit using different parameters in a 5x5 grid:

```
Z=Z.reshape(5, 5)
```

I currently create a contour plot, but it's not meaningful as the Chi-squared values range from 450-700,000 for 550 degrees of freedom.

```
plt.contour(X,Y,Z)
```

Is the chi-squared the correct value to use? Or should I use some delta chi-squared?

The reason I have these values is I used a separate process for my fitting, where I set the output as the minimised Chi-squared.

Comment: I think we need a bit more explanation of what you are intending. Have you thought of converting each value of $\chi^2$ into a probability and plotting them? If that does not work perhaps you can tell us where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If the likelihood function is available, you can construct a 2-dimensional $(1-\alpha)$-[confidence set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_region) for $\theta=(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ based on the quantity $2(l(\hat\theta)-l(\theta)$ where $\hat\theta$ is the MLE of $\theta$.  This pivotal quantity is asymptotically chi-square with 2 degrees of freedom.  Hence,
$$
P(2(l(\hat\theta)-l(\theta))<\chi_{\alpha,2}^2)\approx 1-\alpha.
$$
From this it follows that the set of $\theta=(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ values for which
$$
l(\theta) > l(\hat\theta)-\frac{\chi_{\alpha,2}^2}2 \tag{1}
$$
includes the true parameter value $\theta$ with probability approximately equal to $1-\alpha$.  In practice, you can plot (or compute) this confidence set by setting the `levels` argument of the `contour` (or `contourLines`) function.

If what you call chi-square values are deviances $D$ from a generalized linear model or some other chi-square distributed measure of model fit, these deviances are exactly or at least approximately related to the log likelihood by $D(\theta)=2(l_\text{sat} - l(\theta))$ where $l_\text{sat}$ is the maximum log likelihood under the saturated model.  Hence, in terms these deviance values, the confidence set given by inequality (1) translates to
$$
D(\theta) < D(\hat\theta)+\chi_{\alpha,2}^2.
$$
where $D(\hat\theta)$ is the minimum value of $D(\theta)$ at the best fitting parameters.